# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CONTAINING (1): [IsContaining, Containing, Contains]is not supported for redis query derivation - Redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

I'm developing `Spring Boot + Redis` example. In this example, I've developed some custom methods which pull details based on RoleName. For the below method `userRepository.findByRole_RoleName("ADMIN")` or `userRepository.findByMiddleNameContaining("Li");`, we're getting the below exception.

The reference URL: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/keyvalue/docs/1.2.15.RELEASE/reference/html/

Could anyone please provider pointers ? All the other methods are working fine. But just this method causing the problems. I will post all the required code below for reference.

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:795)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:776)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230)
    at com.baeldung.MainAppDemo.main(MainAppDemo.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CONTAINING (1): [IsContaining, Containing, Contains]is not supported for redis query derivation
    at org.springframework.data.redis.repository.query.RedisQueryCreator.from(RedisQueryCreator.java:67)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.repository.query.RedisQueryCreator.create(RedisQueryCreator.java:53)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.repository.query.RedisQueryCreator.create(RedisQueryCreator.java:41)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:119)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.query.KeyValuePartTreeQuery.createQuery(KeyValuePartTreeQuery.java:211)
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.query.KeyValuePartTreeQuery.prepareQuery(KeyValuePartTreeQuery.java:148)
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.query.KeyValuePartTreeQuery.execute(KeyValuePartTreeQuery.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:602)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy65.findByMiddleNameContains(Unknown Source)
    at com.baeldung.MainAppDemo.run(MainAppDemo.java:38)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:792)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
2018-11-04 00:27:29,639 INFO  [main] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext: Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6f96c77: startup date [Sun Nov 04 00:27:26 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-11-04 00:27:29,645 INFO  [main] org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter: Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

**User.java**

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@RedisHash("user")
public class User {
    private @Id String id;
    private @Indexed String firstName;
    private @Indexed String middleName;
    private @Indexed String lastName;
    private Role role;
}
```

**Role.java**

```
@Data 
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@RedisHash("Role")
public class Role {
    private @Id String id;
    private @Indexed String roleName;
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String>{
    List<User> findByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName, String lastName);

    List<User> findByMiddleNameContains(String firstName);

    List<User> findByRole_RoleName(String roleName);
}
```

MainAppDemo.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainAppDemo implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainAppDemo.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Role role1 = Role.builder().id("R1").roleName("ADMIN").build();
        User user1 = User.builder().firstName("Matt").middleName("Mike").lastName("Wixson").role(role1).build();

        Role role2 = Role.builder().id("R2").roleName("API").build();
        User user2 = User.builder().firstName("John").middleName("Lima").lastName("Kerr").role(role2).build();

        userRepository.save(user1);
        userRepository.save(user2);

        List<User> u = userRepository.findByFirstNameAndLastName("Matt", "Wixson");
        System.out.println("Find By First Name and Last Name = "+u.toString());

        List<User> u2 = userRepository.findByMiddleNameContains("Li");
        System.out.println("Contains ="+u2);

        List<User> adminUser = userRepository.findByRole_RoleName("ADMIN");
        System.out.println("ADMIN USER ="+adminUser);
    }
}
```

JIRA defect: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-887

UPDATE:

I developed the query like this and calling from the main method, still I am getting the same error. Please suggest working solution.

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.middleName LIKE :middleName ")
List<User> findByMiddleNameContaining(@Param("middleName") String middleName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok lets start from "How Redis Work"

Redis work on Hashes for ID which helps in faster location of record. 
@Indexed is also hashed and stored for faster pin-pointing the record

So By Default for MiddleName the "contain" query will not work as Hash for "Test" string will not be contained in Hash for String "TestUser".

But **ExampleMatcher** is here to the rescue.

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#query-by-example

**Solution for RoleName search on Role Object** is relatively simple: Use this query

userRepository.findByRoleRoleName("ADMIN")
(Basically remove the underscore)

And good news is that it can be combined with the above **ExampleMatcher**.

Let's discuss if you have doubt.

Helpfull Reference for RoleName search : [Query Nested Objects in Redis using Spring Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419196/query-nested-objects-in-redis-using-spring-data/49274138#49274138)

Answer (score 0):

On Redis with Spring Boot you just have some queries for finder that are supported like Is, Equals, combine with  And, Or , you can take a look on Table 9:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories.queries

UPDATED

You can create a query following this documentation  link as reference

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#query-by-example

Comment: Is there any alternative solution over using Spring Data Redis? Like Jeddision or raddision which allows me to perform some complex queries?

Comment: You can create a custom query, here is there a reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966967/creating-a-custom-query-with-spring-data-jpa

Comment: @ Jonathan Johx - Query annotation is purely part of the JPA. So Are you saying we should be using JPA API to talk to Redis in case to get data from Custom Query ?

Comment: @ Jonathan Johx - Please see UPDATE, I created Custom Query, still giving the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong the question xD hehe... I'm answering a lot the questions.. Really I'm sorry.

Comment: With Redis you can create queries using an Example, let me add the documentation.. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#query-by-example

Comment: Redis doesn't  seem mature enough to do custom query. I am really struggling to make this working with redis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183081/discussion-between-sayali-and-jonathan-johx).

Comment: Yes, I think that same, I got a couple of issues as you have them.