# Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type User - Redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, jedis, spring-data-redis

I am new to `Redis` and using `Spring Boot + Spring Data Redis` example. In this example, I used the `QueryByExampleRedisExecutor<T>` on repository method and used the `Example` API to do the custom query.

The following is the KEYS present in the Redis NoSQL DB.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
 1) "country:76c78bcc-bb2a-41b3-a1fc-3dbb3042edd6:idx"
 2) "country:76c78bcc-bb2a-41b3-a1fc-3dbb3042edd6"
 3) "user:lastName:Kerr"
 4) "user"
 5) "user:role.roleName:API"
 6) "country:countryName:India"
 7) "Student:name:John Doe"
 8) "user:8252a4b3-22a1-4e6c-99fc-04fed93a21a5:idx"
 9) "user:8252a4b3-22a1-4e6c-99fc-04fed93a21a5"
10) "user:middleName:Lima"
11) "Student"
12) "user:middleName:Mike"
13) "user:firstName:John"
14) "country:countryCode:+91"
15) "user:role.roleName:ADMIN"
16) "user:lastName:Wixson"
17) "Student:1:idx"
18) "user:46ca0606-38a5-4d0c-8cea-38e2c4fa5bfa:idx"
19) "Student:2:idx"
20) "Student:1"
21) "user:firstName:Matt"
22) "user:46ca0606-38a5-4d0c-8cea-38e2c4fa5bfa"
23) "Student:2"
24) "country"
25) "Student:name:Michael Harford"
26) "country:84fc82f2-1c21-4d3e-9429-f1ee1039ceed:idx"
27) "country:84fc82f2-1c21-4d3e-9429-f1ee1039ceed"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Repository method -

```
Example<User> example = Example.of(User.builder().firstName("Mike").build());
long count = userRepository.count();
System.out.println(count);
```

When I execute the below method I was expecting to get only one result, but I am getting two count. Why ?

More Info shown here: [Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate' in your configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53138537/consider-revisiting-the-entries-above-or-defining-a-bean-of-type-org-springfram)

How can we see the `Redis snippet` on the logs ? What configuration do I need to set ?

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String>, QueryByExampleExecutor<User>{
    List<User> findByFirstName(String firstName);

    List<User> findByFirstNameAndLastName(String firstName, String lastName);

    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.middleName LIKE :middleName ")
    List<User> findCustomByMiddleName(@Param("middleName") String middleName); 

    List<User> findByRole_RoleName(String roleName);
}
```

Error below for reference -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:795)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:776)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230)
    at com.baeldung.MainAppDemo.main(MainAppDemo.java:31)
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type User!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:334)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:269)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:252)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:250)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:380)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:381)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.query.KeyValuePartTreeQuery.createQuery(KeyValuePartTreeQuery.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.query.KeyValuePartTreeQuery.prepareQuery(KeyValuePartTreeQuery.java:148)
    at org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.query.KeyValuePartTreeQuery.execute(KeyValuePartTreeQuery.java:106)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:602)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.baeldung.MainAppDemo.run(MainAppDemo.java:47)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:792)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You aren't using the Example, as you are just calling `userRepository.count()` which counts all entries... So basically you are counting all users.

Comment: @M. Deinum - Oh I just realized that. Docs are not very clear and no POC has been provided in order to make the use of it. Could you please post some code how to use Example and SubString queries too ?

Comment: All Entity are annotated with @RedisHash and all CrudRepository works fine. The same has been mentioned in doc. But some usage of Example and ExampleMatcher is not clear

Comment: The exception you post doesn't make sense with the code you show. The code is about `count` the error about `findAll`. However first make sure you are using compatible Spring versions (I assume you are using only the spring boot starters and not try to manage your own Spring Data and Spring Data Redis versions).

Comment: Did you add `@Repository` to `UserRepository`? did you add `@EnableJpaAuditing` to you` @Configuration` class?

Comment: The exception doesn't show problem with counting, it's about missing `findAll`. Could you give the link to Baeldung's code your running?

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing an `Example` but then discard it by not using it. You are calling `userRepository.count();` which basically counts all the records. You should be using the `count` that takes an `Example`.

This method is on the [`QueryByExampleExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/query/QueryByExampleExecutor.html) which your interface, `UserRepository` should extend as well. Then you can simply do.

```
Example<User> example = Example.of(User.builder().firstName("Mike").build());
long count = userRepository.count(example);
System.out.println(count);
```

And you should get the result you expected.

Comment: I am getting this error: Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property count found for type User! See the link in the post for Entity classes

Comment: Have you added the said interface or did you simply add the `count(Example)` method yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue. The solution was to upgrade spring-data-redis and spring-data-common packages to the same version.
In case you are using maven:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```